# Android :HttpGet with Params unsuccessful

Tags: android, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-get

I am using Apache HttpClient, DefaultHttpClient, HttpResponse to make HttpGet Request with JsonObject as request parameter. I receive response in JsonObject format.The Content-Type is application/json

The problem is once a login request fails by providing incorrect login details the next time you correct the details you always fail to get success response.
This scenario doesn't happen if the very first login is successful.

I suspect the params are not going through correctly although I have checked the same. Is there a possibility that the previous request is cached and the new params are not going through.

```
JSONObject inputBodyObject = new JSONObject();
inputBodyObject.put("email", emailId);
inputBodyObject.put("password", password);
String strURL = this.getString(R.string.base_url) + this.getString(R.string.action_login) + Uri.encode(inputBodyObject.toString());

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(strURL);
httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json"));
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Hi have edited the question to include the code snippet.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code shown.

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal Thanks  need to check with server team as well.